# Efficiently serialize/deserialize a SparseDataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, serialization, sparse-matrix, msgpack

#### Has anyone ever efficiently serialized/deserialized a pandas SparseDataFrame?

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy
from scipy import sparse
dfs = pd.SparseDataFrame(scipy.sparse.random(1000, 1000).toarray())
# just for testing
```

#### pickle is not an answer

It's outrageously slow.

```
import pickle, time
start = time.time()
# serialization
msg = list(pickle.dumps(dfs, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))
# deserialization
dfs = pickle.loads(bytes(msg))
stop = time.time()
stop - start
# 0.4420337677001953
# This is with Python 3.5 so it's using cPickle
```

As a comparison msgpack is faster *on the dense version*

```
df = dfs.to_dense()
start = time.time()
# serialization
msg = list(df.to_msgpack(compress='zlib'))
# deserialization
df = pd.read_msgpack(bytes(msg))
stop = time.time()
stop - start
# 0.09514737129211426
```

#### msgpack

Msgpack would be the answer but I can't find an implementation for SparseDataFrame ([related](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23119))

```
# serialization
dfs.to_msgpack(compress='zlib')
# Returns: NotImplementedError: msgpack sparse frame is not implemented
```

#### coordinate format

msgpack on a coordinate format via `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` seems to be worth considering but conversion to `python.sparse.coo_matrix` is slow

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
start = time.time()

# serialization
columns = dfs.columns
shape = dfs.shape
start_to_coo = time.time()
dfc = dfs.to_coo()
stop_to_coo = time.time()
start_comprehension = time.time()
row = [x.item() for x in df.row]
col = [x.item() for x in df.col]
data = [x.item() for x in df.data]
stop_comprehension = time.time()
start_packing = time.time()
msg = list(msgpack.packb({'columns':list(columns), 'shape':shape, 'row':row, 'col':col, 'data':data}))
stop_packing = time.time()

# deserialization
start_unpacking = time.time()
dict = msgpack.unpackb(bytes(msg))
stop_unpacking = time.time()
columns=dict[b'columns']
index=range(dict[b'shape'][0])
dfc = coo_matrix((dict[b'data'], (dict[b'row'], dict[b'col'])), shape=dict[b'shape'])

stop = time.time()
print('total: ' + str(stop - start))
print('  to_coo: ' + str(stop_to_coo - start_to_coo))
print('  comprehension: ' + str(stop_comprehension - start_comprehension))
print('  packing: ' + str(stop_packing - start_packing))
print('  unpacking: ' + str(stop_unpacking - start_unpacking))

#total: 0.2799222469329834
#  to_coo:               0.22925591468811035
#  comprehension & cast: 0.02356100082397461 (msgpack does not support all numpy formats)
#  packing:              0.004893064498901367
#  unpacking:            0.001984834671020508
```

From there it seems one needs to go through a dense format.

```
start = time.time()
dfs = pd.SparseDataFrame(dfc.toarray())
stop = time.time()
stop - start
# 2.8947737216949463
```

Comment: Have you tried `dfs.to_pickle()`? It's much faster than `pickle.dumps`

Comment: No improvement for me. dfs.to_pickle('msg'): 0.06340265274047852. msg = pickle.dumps(dfs): 0.0597076416015625. Both pd.read_pickle and pickle.load take the bulk of the time, equally slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were problems with my tests

```
dfs = pd.SparseDataFrame(scipy.sparse.random(1000, 1000).toarray())
```

doesn't really store a sparse representation. Instead

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame(scipy.sparse.random(1000, 1000).toarray()).to_sparse(fill_value=0)
```

does.

After this, pickle on the sparse representation performs better than msgpack on the dense representation.

In addition, I used `df.row` instead of `dfc.row`. `df` pointed to a different dataframe. msgpack probably had the result in cache and didn't do anything.

After correcting this error, msgpack on the coo_matrix-based representation doesn't improve over pickle on the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead in time stems from the string handling in `dumps` and `loads`.

Using `dumps/loads`:

```
def pickle_dumps():
    msg = list(pickle.dumps(dfs, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))
    pickle.loads(bytes(msg))

%timeit pickle_dumps()
# 212 ms ± 2.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Using `dump/load`:

```
def pickle_file():
    with open('dump.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(dfs, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    with open('dump.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

%timeit pickle_file()
# 82.7 ms ± 1.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Or even shorter using pandas builtins:

```
def to_pickle():    
    dfs.to_pickle('./dump.pickle')
    pd.read_pickle('./dump.pickle')

%timeit to_pickle()
# 86.8 ms ± 1.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I don't see the difference that you see. There might have been another process running in the same time as your pickle_dumps experiment

Comment: So you're saying the dump/load version is not 2x as fast as the dumps/loads version? Which python are you using (I have 3.6.6)?